# Replace TinyMCE with Custom Built Editor

Tags: php, functions, tinymce

I am looking to build a custom wiziwig, and replace wordpress's TinyMCE all together. I figured out how to add to the TinyMCE editor, but thats not what im looking for. Does anyone have any references for a starting point? Googling it only came up with the option to add to TinyMCE, not replace it with something custom all together. Something detailed would be great. I really just need a starting point, then I should be able to get it from there.

Let me know if you have any questions

Thanks in advance,
Zac

Comment: that is a very open ended question.... editor for what and what features you want to support in it.

Comment: Im wanting to design my own from scratch, however I dont know how to replace the tinymce editor thats there. A perfect example for what im looking for is https://theme-fusion.com/support/documentation/avada-documentation/#page-item-269354 The ability to 'toggle' which editor you use. Does that help?

Comment: not really, writing a new editor take months if not years and I assume that you are thinking of it as a "summer project". With new editor how will you support the insertion and edit of media, how will you be able to switch to text mode and back? If you don't care about it then it is easy, but still you at least need to give some information how the editor will be instantiated.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with js/jquery if you want :

```
$('#postdivrich').hide().after(your custom editor div);
```

You can add inputs with jquery and save them with :

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_the_post');
function save_the_post(){
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_name', $_POST['field_name']);
}
```

Or use a metabox and replace standard editor with it (width jquery).

Hope this help someone :)

Comment: :( that is the least important detail

Comment: The next step is the simplest part of the job, just add some inputs, and save them with the "save_post" hook.